# How do I write a regex to get specific period of dates?

Tags: regex, grep

I need to write a regex  that returns all dates between May 1st and August 5, 2017 and does not
match dates outside of this range. I have to use the grep command for this.

The dates in the file are given in this format YYYY-MM-DD

So far i got this code, but I dont know how i can grab the dates in August till the 5th without limiting it for the other months:

```
grep "2017[-/][05-08][-/]xx"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: With `awk` it's much easier: `awk '$1 >= "2017-05-01" && $1 <= "2017-08-05"' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -e '2017-0[567]' -e '2017-08-0[1-5]' file
```

or

```
grep -E '2017-0[567]|2017-08-0[1-5]' file
```

or

```
grep -E '2017-0([567]|8-0[1-5])' file
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)